# C# getting AJAX call

Tags: c#, javascript, ajax

I want to send a JavaScript AJAX call to a C# server every few seconds, I have all the client side ready, how would I read it server side and send a reply? I know AJAX stands for Asynchronous JavaScript and XML so there might be no way at all I searched google and found nothing.

Also what is the maximum size of a message you can pass between every ajax call?

Comment: So you know how to make an Ajax Call? Do you know how to use setTimeout?

Comment: You'll want to create a `Web Service` in C#. http://dotnetguts.blogspot.com/2012/01/jquery-ajax-examples-by-calling-aspnet.html

Comment: A php translation server seems like a possible option

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create your own webserver in C# using TCPListener class. With that you can get all the data sent to console application (including header data) and respond to it.

There's more information with a complete sample in at the following website:

[Create your own Web Server using C#](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1505/Create-your-own-Web-Server-using-C)

Comment: Seems like just what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

One easy way to get input back from c# is to create a empty aspx page.  Inside the page load check for any parameters then return the data using.

```
Response.Write("Data To Return");
Response.End();
```

I have used this method for returning paging for a ajax driven grid.

Page With Ajax: MyPage.aspx

I call MyPage_JSON.aspx to retrieve the data by passing parameters to the page using querystring variables.  MyPage_JSON.aspx?start=1&increment=20

MyPage_JSON.aspx returns, as you would expect, JSON which is then parsed by the javascript in MyPage.aspx and displayed to the user.

Really no maximum only limited by the performance of the application (Client Browser).  If you try and return too much data your call could hang.

Comment: I need a C# console app though

Comment: You'll have to host your own web server in C#. There are components to do this. You might want to use ASP.NET Web API which has a component where you can "self host" a small web server inside your console app without needing everything to run inside the full IIS.

Comment: If you absolutely need a c# console app you will need to do as Jesper said. look into the System.Net.HttpListener class.